# Displaying images based on the selected ids using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter

[image]How to display images based on selecting ids.While adding portfolio images i am inserting data into two tables as portfolio table and portfolio_tags table.

I am having three tables portfolio,tags and portfolio_tags.

```
portfolio
=============
portfolio_id        image_path 
1                   image.png           
2                   imag.png           
3                   images.png            
4                   img.png            
5                   imagess.png 

Tags table:
==========
tag_id     tag_name
 1       All
 2       CMS
 3       DESIGN

 portfolio_tag
 =============
 portfolio_id        tag_id  portfolio_tag_id
 1                   1            1
 1                   2            2
 2                   3            3
 3                   1            4
```

I will be fetching all the tags data as well as the portfolio data.While opening the page it will display all the data related to all the tags.But when we select particular only the information related to that tag to be displayed.
Ex:If i select CMS it should display only that information relation to CMS and if i select DESIGN only the information related to that tag should be displayed.

Can any one suggest me how to do that.

Here is my code.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('portfolio_model');
    $data["records2"] = $this->portfolio_model->get_portfolio();
    $data["records3"] = $this->portfolio_model->get_tags();
    $data['mainpage'] = "portfolio";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
 }
```

Model:

```
function get_portfolio($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->Select('portfolio.*');
    $this->db->From('portfolio');
    $this->db->where(array('portfolio.status'=>1));
    $q=$this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)      
    {       
        return $q->result();
     }
        else
        {
    return false;
  }
}
function get_tags()
{
    $this->db->Select('tags.*');
    $this->db->From('tags');
    $q=$this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)      
    {       
        return $q->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php  $this->load->view('tagss');?>
                    <?php 
                    $cnt = 0;
                    if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
                    <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>  
                    <div class="portfolioimages">                   
                      <a href="<?php echo $r->website_url;?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/portfolio/thumbs/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php 

                    if(($cnt%3) == 0) { echo "<br>"; }          
                    $cnt++; 
                    endforeach; endif;?>
```

Tags

```
<?php if(isset($records3) && is_array($records3)):?>
    <?php foreach ($records3 as $r):?> 
        <div class="materials">         
            <div class="class453">
                <a href="#"  class="read_more12"><?php echo $r->tag_name;?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endforeach ;endif;?>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.materials a').not('.materials a:first').addClass('opacty');
$('.materials a').click(function(e){
$('.materials a').not(this).addClass('opacty');
$(this).removeClass('opacty'); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you mean when we click on some particular tag like 'design', the portfolio images should get filtered and only the portfolio_image of 'design' tag should be shown?

Comment: first i will show all the images of all the tags.If i select any tag only the images of that particular tag should be displayed.

Comment: okay..so it's the only requirement in the code, right?

Comment: I have shared screenshot here you can check by default it will be ALL where i will display all the images.Next if i select design or cms only the images related to that tag should be displayed not all the images.

Comment: @sheetal yes we need to change in code itself

Comment: i guess you don't have provided the correct table column-names..if not please add the correct column names here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128917/discussion-between-user7047368-and-sheetal).

Comment: anyone who can help me from  this problem please

Comment: Anyone please help me these i just strucked not getting how to do that please anyone help me out these thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing filtered images on clicking different tagNames, we can use ajax. So at first we need to create a new function in the Controller class which would display the fetched images url for the tag_id as the json object.

Add the function below to you controller.

```
public function tag_data($id){
    $this->load->model('portfolio_model');
    $data = array();
    $tagged_result = $this->portfolio_model->get_tag_images($id); // call to model function
    $tagged_images = array();

    foreach($tagged_result as $tag){
        $tagged_images[] = $tag->image_path;
    }
    echo json_encode($tagged_images);
}
```

In the code above I've called the function `get_tag_images($id)` which fetches all the images url from the database which are related to the tag_id.

Append the code below to the model class

```
public function get_tag_images($id){
    $query = $this->db->select('image_path')->from('portfolio_tag')->join('portfolio',"portfolio_tag.portfolio_id = portfolio.portfolio_id")->where("tag_id", $id)->group_by('portfolio.portfolio_id')->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)     
        return $query->result();
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now we have to make some changes in the tags view.

View:

```
<?php 
$cnt = 0;
if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
    <div id="portfolio">
        <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>  
            <div class="portfolioimages">                   
              <a href="<?php echo $r->website_url;?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/portfolio/thumbs/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" /></a>
            </div>
            <?php 

            if(($cnt%3) == 0) { echo "<br>"; }          
            $cnt++; 
        endforeach; ?> 
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Edit Tags view:

```
<?php if(isset($records3) && is_array($records3)):?>
    <?php foreach ($records3 as $r):?> 
        <div class="materials">         
            <div class="class453">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="read_more12">
                    <span style="display:none"><?php echo $r->tag_id; ?></span> // this contains the tag_id
                    <?php echo $r->tag_name;?>
                </a> 
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endforeach ;endif;?>
```

Ajax -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.materials div a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var tagId = $(this).find('span').html();
        var url   = '<?php echo base_url('portfolio/tag_data/'); ?>'+ tagId;
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:  url,
          data: {'tagid': tagId},
          success: function(data){
            var taggedImgs = $.parseJSON(data);
            var inc = 0;
            var unTag = [];
            var portfolioImages =  $('.portfolioimages a img').map(function(){
                    var url = $(this).attr('src').split('/');
                    return url[url.length-1];
                });

            $('.portfolioimages a img').each(function(e){
                    imgUrl      = $(this).attr('src').split('/');
                    var imgPath = imgUrl[imgUrl.length-1];
                    // compare the tagged image with portfolio images url
                    if($.inArray(imgPath, taggedImgs) == -1){
                        // image doesn't matched
                        $(this).remove();
                    } 

                });
            jQuery.each(taggedImgs, function(idx, tagImg){
                var flag = false;
                if($.inArray(tagImg, portfolioImages) == -1){
                    // image doesn't exist
                    $('#portfolio').append("<div class='portfolioimages'><a href='<?php echo base_url('index.php/portfolio'); ?>' target='_blank'><img src='<?php echo base_url('admin/images/portfolio/thumbs/'); ?>/"+tagImg+"'></a></div>");
                }

            });

          },
          error: function(err){
            alert("Some error occured! "+ err);
          }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: sure and please update your view too..i've made an edit, you can check that

Comment: ya i have updated view and everything getting a popup error as some error occured![object object]

Comment: i've used the demo url in the ajax that's whythis error is coming up, just add the correct url in the ajax url..that would fix it

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: changed the url var url   = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/portfolio/tag_data/'+ tagId; got this error

Comment: do it like this: var url = '<?php echo base_url('index.php/portfolio/tag_data/'); ?>+tagId';

Comment: just use the url of the newly created 'tag_data' function [in controller] here with tagId

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129004/discussion-between-sheetal-and-user7047368).